# How to extract the lines that have the given sequence?

Tags: awk, command-line, sed

I am trying to find a command that is extracting only the lines that have all their characters in a sequence and in the order as below from a text file.

800900100011001200..(descending by 100)
369121518 (ascending by 3)

Can I do this in one command to print only the lines that have only above orders or have to make one command for every sequence?

Comment: Is `1245` a sequence? (12, and 45 ascending by 33 or 124 and 5 descending by 119) or does the sequence have to have at least 3 items?

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas this sequence 369121518.. is ascending by 3 as 3 6 9 12 15 18 ...can you help me with a command that governing that?

Comment: @Kusalananda i have tried

(?:036|369|6912|912|1215|1218|)  but its not working with me and also in this wsy I have to mention all the sequsence in my command i want governining command for that.

Answer (score 3):

One approach using `perl`'s `(??{...})` experimental regex operator for sequences of 3 or more decimal numbers in linear sequence:

```
perl -lne 'print if m{^(\d+)(\d+)(?=(.+$))(??{
  my $i = $2; my $r; my $l = length $3; my $incr = $2 - $1;
  while (length($r) < $l) {$i += $incr; $r .= $i}; $r})$}'
```

Note that it reports on `000000`, as that's 0000, 0, 0 or 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 and also on `1023` as that's 1, 02, 3, but the way it works, not on `1203` as the way it works, for the part after the first 2 numbers, it expects a list of numbers without leading 0s.

Similarly, it reports `10-1`, but not `-101` as a `-` is not expected in the first two numbers.

You could address that with:

```
perl -lne 'print if m{^(-?\d+)(-?\d+)(?=(.+$))(??{
  my $i = $2; my $r, $sign, $value; my $m = $3; my $incr = $2 - $1;
  while (($i += $incr),
         (($sign, $value) = ($i =~ /(-?)(\d*)/)),
         $m =~ /^(${sign}0*$value)(.*)/) {
    $r .= $1; $m = $2;
  }; $r})$}'
```

With which it would report `12000034`, `-101`, `-1-2-3`, `0-123-246`...

Comment: Chazelas its ok thanks but could you please edit it to exclude the last or the last two characters in the line if they are not belong to the sequences above for example print this lines 24685 or 246853.

Comment: For that, you could replace the last `$r` with `$r eq "" ? $r : "$r\\d{0,2}"`

Comment: Dear Stephane Chazelas your commands are ok and worked fine with me..Now I have an equation for descending sequence and ascending sequence and now please I just need an edition for your commad to detect the lines that have both ascending and descending sequence in the same line for example: 246642 or 3698642. And I will be very appreciated.

Comment: Chazelas Replacing the last $r with $r eq "" ? $r : "$r\\d{0,2}" is not working correctly with your first perl command.

Comment: Chazelas could you please add this exclusion "$r with $r eq "" ? $r : "$r\\d{0,2}" to your first perl command.

Comment: @@Stephane Chazelas: Could you please add this exclusion "$r with $r eq "" ? $r : "$r\\d{0,2}" to your first perl command.